# Android Market - Application isn't available for devices

Tags: android, google-play

I published my APK to Android market. I can search it via `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=[package name]`, but I can't install it on my Nexus One device which running `Android OS 2.3.6`, the popup shows `not compatible with your device`. The manifest file is configured as below:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />      
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

What problem in my configuration made My Nexus One device is filtered?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your manifest; I'd wager you have Copy Protection enabled. From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html#other-filters):

> To copy protect an application, set copy protection to "On" when you
> configure publishing options for your application. Google Play will
> not show copy-protected applications on developer devices or
> unreleased devices.

Since the Nexus One is a developer device, it will show as incompatible. I  ran into this same issue on my Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Hi kcoppock, the Copy protection checkbox isn't enabled. By the way, I tried to check on some more devices but have the same problem, the application isn't compatible for them

Comment: Really? Hmm. That's interesting. Are there any devices in particular that *have* worked so far?

Comment: Currently, no devices can install my application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />//=======> the target version is your wish(> 10)
```

Comment: Hi Ram kiran, thanks for your answer. I will check it. I added:<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />